# Q: How many classes will the following code generate?

Tags: c++, class

I find this question tricky. What do u ppl think?

```
template <typename T> class myTemplate
{
public:
   T val;
...
};
void myFunction()
{
   MyTemplate<int> a;
   MyTemplate<double> b;
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this is actually implementation defined, the implementation might or might not generate 2 classes. The optimizer might even optimize your class out if it's especially clever :)

Comment: I thought the answer is 2 classes. One for each type needed... Btw, why people are down voting my question? It's not ok formulated? I'm new here Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating the template twice with two different template parameters, so it'll create two class instances.